# Jmslistener in springboot app not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, ibm-mq, spring-jms, mq

I have setup a Kotlin Springboot app and trying to listen to MQ queue but the listener is not working. The app is running and I drop a message but the `JmsListener` is not picking it up. My code is below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
open class MainApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MainApplication>(*args)
}
```

```
@Configuration
open class MqConfig {
    @Value("\${jms.mq.port}")
    private var port: Int = 0

    @Value("\${jms.mq.channel}")
    private var channel: String? = null

    @Value("\${jms.mq.host}")
    private var host: String? = null

    @Value("\${jms.mq.manager}")
    private var queueManager: String? = null

    @Bean
    open fun jmsMQConnectionFactory(): MQConnectionFactory {
        val mqQueueConnectionFactory = MQConnectionFactory()
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.port = port
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.channel = channel
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.hostName = host
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.queueManager = queueManager
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.transportType = WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT
        mqQueueConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, "true")

        return SingleConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory)
    }

    @Bean
    open fun jmsListenerContainerFactory(): JmsListenerContainerFactory<*> {
        val factory = DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory()
        factory.setAutoStartup(true)
        factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsMQConnectionFactory())
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true)
        return factory
    }
```

```
@Component
class QueueListener {

    @JmsListener(destination = "\${jms.mqA.queue}", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    @Throws(JMSException::class)
    fun receiveMessge(message: Message) {
        println((message as TextMessage).text)
    }
```

Is there any obvious mistake in my code? Why the publisher not working? In the logs I don't see anything and the messages are still on MQ (not picked up by my listener).... How to debug this?? any help appreciated.

Comment: You are using QueueListener but have set setPubSubDomain to true. Any reason using setPubSubDomain(true)?

Comment: @Shashi that shouldn't affect the OP's issue.

Comment: Why is there a \ in the destination? \${jms.mqA.queue}

Comment: Because this is kotlin code and that is the way to do `@Value` in Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

@Shashi does have a point. If you have `factory.setPubSubDomain(true)`, then although your Spring code doesn't change, you are using topics and not queues.

Consequently I would expect that `jms.mqA.queue` in `application.properties` to be a topic and not a queue.

I know that this is just speculation and all this depends on what you have `jms.mqA.queue` set to in `application.properties`, but you haven't shared that bit of configuration. Naming it `jms.mqA.queue` is a little misleading, I would have gone for `jms.mqA.destination`.

> > Added after comment discussion.

It may be overkill, but try adding the following decorations to your application.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@EnableJms
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: Removing that line does not fix the problem.

Comment: Add logging in your listener container factory to verify that it is actually starting up.